# how use replace in exec statement in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, replace, exec

I have a stored proc, say, "call_Me" with few parameters:

```
Declare @Greet varchar(100) = 'Hi ||User||'

Exec Call_Me 1,'something', @Greet --parameters: bit, string, string
```

during the call, I want to be able to replace the

```
||User||
```

bit with something else. normally, in a select statement, I would do this:

```
select 1, 'something', Replace(@Greet, '||User||', u.Username) from UserTable
```

which works fine, But today, for the first time, I am trying to use it in exec statement, the error says its expecting select, I tried adding select in every possible (and sensible) way but it just didnt seem to work out.

How can I use a replace during an execute statement call?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give an example of call of stored procedure with replacing? Do you want to call this SP in loop (for many usernames)?

Comment: that SP just inserts the given data into a table, but checks for some validation and foreign keys on the way..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to format @Greet before passing it to the sproc:

```
Declare @Greet varchar(100) = 'Hi ||User||'
SELECT @Greet = Replace(@Greet, '||User||', u.Username) 
FROM UserTable u
WHERE Id = 1

Exec Call_Me 1,'something', @Greet --parameters: bit, string, string
```

Comment: I thougt of this, but the downside is that once I replace the original string, ||user|| will not be in there anymore so I cant use it again. but I think I will do this with another variable. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use a literal or a variable reference in a procedure call:

```
[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]
    { 
      [ @return_status= ]
      { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var } 
        [ [ @parameter= ] { value 
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ] 
                           | [ DEFAULT ] 
                           }
        ]
      [ ,...n ]
      [ WITH RECOMPILE ]
    }
[;]
```

Use this:

```
Declare @Greet varchar(100) = 'Hi ||User||'
Declare @param VARCHAR(100) = REPLACE(@Greet, '||User||', 'replacement')

Exec Call_Me 1,'something', @param
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly your problem, but maybe **using cursor** solves your problem:

```
DECLARE CURSOR users LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT 
        username
    FROM
        usertable

OPEN

DECLARE @username NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Greet VARCHAR(100) = 'Hi ||User||'

FETCH NEXT FROM users INTO @username

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    EXEC Call_Me 1, 'something', REPLACE(@Greet, '||User||', @username)

    FETCH NEXT FROM users INTO @username
END

CLOSE users
DEALLOCATE users
```

If you **don't need** to call it **in loop** you can try something like (this can be a new stored procedure):

```
DECLARE @username NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Greet VARCHAR(100) = 'Hi ||User||'

SELECT
    @username = username
FROM
    usernames
WHERE
    user_id = 1

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1 BEGIN
    EXEC Call_Me 1, 'something', REPLACE(@Greet, '||User||', @username)
END
```